# match two data.frames and save on a different files

Tags: r

I have a very difficult problem. I have two data.frames like this:

data.frame_1 (600 columns and 100 rows):

> ```
>  COL1   COL2   COL3  ...
>   ab     e     jh    ...   
>   gb     if    ki    ...    
>   uc     kg    al    ...    
>   id     mn    ef1   ...
> ```

and data.frame2 (900 columns and 1000 rows)

> ```
>  Gene  Samp1   Samp2  Samp3
>   ab     1      0      0
>   gb     1      1      1
>   uc     0     -1      1
>   id    -1     -1      1
>   e      1      0     -1
>   f     -1      1     -1
>   if     1      1      0
>   kg     0      1     -1
>   mn    -1      0      1
>   jh    -1     -1     -1
>   ki     0     -1      0
>   al     0      1     -1
> ```

I would like the following output:

> ```
>  COL1    Samp1   Samp2   Samp3
>   ab      1        0      0
>   gb      1        1      1
>   uc      0       -1      1
>   id     -1       -1      1
>
>
>
>
>  COL2    Samp1   Samp2   Samp3
>   e        1       0      -1
>   f       -1       1      -1
>   if       1       1       0
>   kg       0       1      -1
> ```

So, for each column of data.frame_1 I need a match and subset with the first column of data.frame_2
and then each match will be saved on a different separate file.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite simple, actually:

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "COL1   COL2   COL3 
   ab     e     jh       
   gb     if    ki        
   uc     kg    al        
   id     mn    ef1   ",header = TRUE,sep = "")
dat2 <- read.table(text=  "Gene  Samp1   Samp2  Samp3
   ab     1      0      0
   gb     1      1      1
   uc     0     -1      1
   id    -1     -1      1
   e      1      0     -1
   f     -1      1     -1
   if     1      1      0
   kg     0      1     -1
   mn    -1      0      1
   jh    -1     -1     -1
   ki     0     -1      0
   al     0      1     -1",header = TRUE,sep = "")

lapply(dat1,function(x) dat2[dat2$Gene %in% x,])
```

And then you have a list of data frames containing the results. Just `lapply` over it to save each to a separate file (assuming that your really want each in a file on disk).

Comment: I was going to suggest `lapply(dat1,function(x) merge(data.frame(Col=x), dat2, by.x="Col", by.y="Gene") )` but yours looks cleaner